# Add new field to all documents in a nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have a database of person documents. Each has a field named photos, which is an array of photo documents. I would like to add a new 'reviewed' flag to each of the photo documents and initialize it to false.

This is the query I am trying to use:

```
db.person.update({ "_id" : { $exists : true } }, {$set : {photos.reviewed : false} }, false, true)
```

However I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1
```

Is this possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong in my update?

Here is a full example of the 'person' document:

```
{
"_class" : "com.foo.Person",
"_id" : "2894",
"name" : "Pixel Spacebag",
"photos" : [
    {
        "_id" : null,
        "thumbUrl" : "http://site.com/a_s.jpg",
        "fullUrl" : "http://site.com/a.jpg"
    },
    {
        "_id" : null,
        "thumbUrl" : "http://site.com/b_s.jpg",
        "fullUrl" : "http://site.com/b.jpg"
    }]
}
```

Bonus karma for anyone who can tell me a cleaner why to update "all documents" without using the query `{ "_id" : { $exists : true } }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong in my update?

No. In general MongoDB is only good at doing updates on top-level objects.

The exception here is the [$ positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The$positionaloperator). From the docs: `Use this to find an array member and then manipulate it`.

However, in your case you want to modify all members in an array. So that is not what you need.

> Bonus karma for anyone who can tell me a cleaner why to update "all documents"

Try `db.coll.update(query, update, false, true)`, this will issue a "multi" update. That last `true` is what makes it a multi.

> Is this possible,

You have two options here:

1. Write a `for` loop to perform the update. It will basically be a nested `for` loop, one to loop through the data, the other to loop through the sub-array. If you have a lot of data, you will want to write this is your driver of choice (*and possibly multi-thread it*).
2. Write your code to handle `reviewed` as nullable. Write the data such that if it comes across a photo with `reviewed` undefined then it must be `false`. Then you can set the field appropriately and commit it back to the DB.

Method #2 is something you should get used to. As your data grows and you add fields, it becomes difficult to "back-port" all of the old data. This is similar to the problem of issuing a schema change in SQL when you have 1B items in the DB.

Instead just make your code resistant against the `null` and learn to treat it as a default.

Again though, this is still not the solution you seek.

Comment: Good answer. To clarify what I was looking for for the "bonus" was a way to update all documents with a "simple" query (something more simple than "{"_id":{$exists:true}}". I understand the "multi" param, but I still need a query that matches all documents. I thought maybe "{}" would match all documents, but I don't think so?

Comment: And no, this isn't a "solution", but is a good explanation for why I simply cannot achieve what I am looking for with the curent version of mongodb (2.0.2). If a solution does become available, please post another answer for future users.

Comment: Possible now in mongo 3.6

Answer (score 27):

For those who are still looking for the answer it is possible with MongoDB 3.6 with the all positional operator `$[]` see the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/):

```
db.getCollection('person').update(
   {},
   { $set: { "photos.$[].reviewed" : false } },
   { multi: true}
)
```

Comment: awesome. just what I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
(null, {$set : {"photos.reviewed" : false} }, false, true)
```

The first parameter is null : no specification = any item in the collection.

"photos.reviewed" should be declared as string to update subfield.

Comment: you can't do this. It fails with `assert failed : need a query`

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
db.person.update({}, $set:{name.surname:null}, false, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Old topic now, but this just worked fine with Mongo 3.0.6:

`db.users.update({ _id: ObjectId("55e8969119cee85d216211fb") },
    { $set: {"settings.pieces": "merida"} })`

In my case user entity looks like

```
{ _id: 32, name: "foo", ..., settings: { ..., pieces: "merida", ...} }
```

Comment: You don't have an array, as is in the question.